# Fit an element according of another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to fit two divs around the header-title, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not sure that the calc() works well with the javascript. Here is the code so far:

```js
document.getElementByClass('Header').clientWidth;
```

```css
:root {
  --main-accent-color: #3500D3;
  --main-bg-color: #282828;
  --secondary-bg-color: #0c0032;
  --main-content-bg-color: #190061;
  --text-color: #ffffff;
  --alt-color: #240090;
}

* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;

}

body {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}

h1 {
  font-family: robot0, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-variant: petite-caps;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.header {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom: 5px solid var(--main-accent-color);
}

.header-title {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  height: 85px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-left: 5px solid var(--main-accent-color);
  border-right: 5px solid var(--main-accent-color);
  z-index: 11
}

.header-info {
  width: calc((clientWidth - 500) / 2);
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#right-info {
  right: calc(((clientWidth - 500) / 2) + 500);
}

#left-info {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Webpage</title>
    <script>
      document.getElementByClass('header').clientWidth;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Header-->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-title">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="header-info" id="left-info">
        <p>
        Hi
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="header-info" id="right-info">
        <p>
        Hi
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

If there is another method that I can use, that would be great. Also, I am learning CSS right now, so I am not confident with JavaScript at all, I only used it because that's how other people did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it too complicated. I removed a lot of code and added [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for the header. Both divs at the side are allowed to [grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) as much as space allows.

```css
:root {
  --main-accent-color: #3500D3;
  --main-bg-color: #282828;
  --secondary-bg-color: #0c0032;
  --main-content-bg-color: #190061;
  --text-color: #ffffff;
  --alt-color: #240090;
}

* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}

h1 {
  font-family: robot0, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-variant: petite-caps;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 5px solid var(--main-accent-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
}

.header-title {
  width: 500px;
  border-left: 5px solid var(--main-accent-color);
  border-right: 5px solid var(--main-accent-color);
  text-align: center;
}

.header-info {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-info">
    <p>
      Hi
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="header-title">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="header-info">
    <p>
      Hi
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I will look into flex bot as I haven't used him yet :)